# Replacement of getUserMedia() for mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, getusermedia

I am aware that iOS does not support getUserMedia(). Is there a way to bypass that to stream video or capture image from the video stream, on an iOS and android mobile browser?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into Video -elements 'srcObject' attribute https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/srcObject. It's still experimental feature but example for latest version of Safari it's the way to capture video stream. Also some of the mobile browsers supports it.

In my opinion you should combine this with getMediaDevices() -feature and that way you get quiet large device support range. I have approach this with conditionally checking which features users browser supports.